# AngularJS: how to push multiple selected items and save into database

Tags: php, angularjs, rest, laravel

I have a rest api setup in laravel 5. The front-end is AngularJS. I am a little confused on how to, after the user selects multiple items using `ui-select`, to save this in the database.

**Questions**

1- How should I send the selected data into the API?

2- Laravel: how to update multiple **existing** records.

Now I know laravel has `saveMany()` out of the box. But the question remains on how to do that?

I could't find any resource which I can benefit from. Would someone please help me out.

Comment: The Laravel Docs do a great job and give many examples of how to save/attach related Eloquent models: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

Comment: AngularJS part: [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) and  [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) services.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav I do have everything setup. I know how $http works But just wondering how should I push the selected data into the AP i

Comment: You should add this array to your request body in query params or if you use post request in post body as json

Comment: @SharikovVladislav Do you have an example to show me?

Comment: Already. And yes, this must be accepted :D I did work for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two parts. You have to send AJAX request from AngularJS to your API, which is implemented by Laravel.

## AngularJS part

You need [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) to make AJAX request. You need `$http.post`:

```
var module = angular.module('myApp', []);
module.controller('myCtrl', ['$http', function ($http) {
  var someArray = [{id: 1, name: 'name1'}, {id: 2, name: 'name2'}];
  $http.post('/api/entities/batchUpdate', {data: someArray}).success(function (data) {
    // handle response there
  });
}]);
```

## Laravel part:

You need to create route:

```
Route::put('entities/batchUpdate' , array('uses' => 'MyCtrl@batchEntitiesUpdate'));
```

Also you need to implement method for you `MyCtrl` controller.

```
public function batchEntitiesUpdate()
{
    $input = (object)Input::all();
    $jsonArray = $input->data;
    foreach ($jsonArray as $item) {
        $item = (object) $item;

        $entity = Entity::find($item->id)
        $entity->name = $item->name;
        $entity->save();
    }

    /* return return some response */
}
```

Comment: Wonderful!! Thank you!

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean by `$jsonArray = $input->data;`

Comment: You have _some_ structure in you JSON object. You put it into `$input` by `(object)Input::all()`. Then by `$input->data` you access `data` property of this object.